# Nested Map or equivalent to store triple

Tags: java, dictionary, nested-lists

I have to store values into a list/map which contains three values:

```
size  |   amount |  description
2,34  |     4    |  "I'm a long String"
1,14  |     2    |  "I'm another long String"
```

So I thought about using a nested Map like :

```
        Map<Double, Map<Integer,String>> a = new HashMap<Double, Map<Integer,String>>();
```

But how can I easy add entries to that Map?
Syntax like

```
a.put(1,43, new Map.Entry<>(7,"9890"));
```

didn't work, cause `Map` is abstract. What is the best way to get my nested Map?

Comment: Encapsulation is your friend. Create a class for your triple.

Comment: To expand on what @SotiriosDelimanolis is saying, why not create a class to describe what the pairing of amount and description is. Then you can just use a Map<Double,TheNewClass> - or possibly even make a class to encapsulate all three pieces of information and just store it in a set or something (depending on what your particular use case is)

Comment: What is the purpose of this collection?  Do you need to access it with a key?

Comment: Finally I want to search the entry with the smalles size value from my map and then the entry with the smalles amount value into these size. A own class to realize would be the best solution, but I'm not allowed to do it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a HashMap value with three values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148331/how-to-get-a-hashmap-value-with-three-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to be tedious:

```
Map<Integer,String> val1 = a.get(2.34);
if (val1 == null) {
    val1 = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
    a.put(2.34, val1);
}
val1.put(4, "I'm a long String");
```

I've **updated** it to TreeMap since you want to access the smallest element. You should also change the map "a" to be a TreeMap too.

**EDIT 2**

I made an effort here, hope it's what you're looking for :)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        TreeMap<Double, TreeMap<Integer, String>> map = new TreeMap<>();
        add(2.5, 5, "wrong value 1", map);
        add(3, 2, "wrong value 2", map);
        add(2.5, 3, "good value", map);

        System.out.println(map.pollFirstEntry().getValue().pollFirstEntry().getValue());
    }
    public static void add(double val1, int val2, String val3, TreeMap<Double, TreeMap<Integer, String>> map) {
        TreeMap<Integer,String> subMap = map.get(val1);
        if (subMap == null) {
            subMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
            map.put(val1, subMap);
        }
        subMap.put(val2, val3);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just define an Entry class:

```
final class Entry {
    final int amount;
    final String description;

    Entry(final int amount, final String description) {
        // check parameters
        this.amount = amount;
        this.description = description;
    }


    // implement getAmount
    // implement getDescription
}
```

and the type of the map is

```
Map<Double, Entry>
```

Comment: Wouldn't work if you have to "Entries" for the same double value.

Comment: Why do it half-way? Better to implement a single class for all three data elements and then create an appropriate collection for it, be it Map, List, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sotirios Delimanolis mentioned you should create class for your tripple and choose collection according to your needs. If you just want to store your objects and then probably iterate over them use `List`. If you have to allow access to your objects using simple or complex unique key use `Map`.

But be careful: never use `Double` as key of `Map`. Two "equal" values of type `double` might be not equal in practice, so you will get duplicate entries.