# Can there be a HashMap with 3 different types in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I have a **HashMap** like

```
Map<String, JPanel> MapItems = new HashMap<String, JPanel>();
```

What if I want to put third value as well in a Map or List something like this

```
Map<String, JPanel, JLabel> MapItems = new HashMap<String, JPanel, JLabel>();
```

it doesn't matter if I have to call with element position instead String Value so it isn't necessary to use Map only but if there is some other way around please tell me. I just want to put my `JPanel` and `JLabel` together.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148331/how-to-get-a-hashmap-value-with-three-values

Comment: No In that question all 3 values were string but in my question I have all 3 values different

Comment: Make a new class and use as many data types you need and use in HashMap

Comment: That doesn't matter too much. Most if not all of those answers will work for you. Equivalent answer to Aeshang's answer is in this question where you use a map that maps a string to a map or you can create a composite key or you can use an object wrapper arround Jpanel and JLabel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create another Object to wrap it and save the combination of your JPanel and JLabel, something like that:

```
public class WrapperTest {

    private JPanel jPanel;
    private JLabel jLabel;

    public WrapperTest(JPanel jPanel, JLabel jLabel) {
        super();
        this.jPanel = jPanel;
        this.jLabel = jLabel;
    }

    public JPanel getjPanel() {
        return jPanel;
    }
    public void setjPanel(JPanel jPanel) {
        this.jPanel = jPanel;
    }
    public JLabel getjLabel() {
        return jLabel;
    }
    public void setjLabel(JLabel jLabel) {
        this.jLabel = jLabel;
    }

}
```

And use your hash this way:

```
Map<String, WrapperTest> mapItems = new HashMap<String, WrapperTest>();
```

Example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel();
        JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();

        WrapperTest wrapper1 = new WrapperTest(jPanel1, jLabel1);

        Map<String, WrapperTest> mapItems = new HashMap<String, WrapperTest>();
        mapItems.put("key1", wrapper1);

    }

}
```

Comment: How do you put and get items in this map?

Comment: Edited with a better example for you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way. Make an object wrapper around `JPanel` and `JLabel` and use that as the value.

```
class JWrapper {
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel label;
    // Constructor, getters, setters ...
}

// ...
HashMap<String, JWrapper> map = new HashMap<String, JWrapper>();
// ...
```

Comment: How do you put and get items in this map?

Comment: Same way you would put items in any map. Create a `JWrapper` object. `JWrapper wrap = new JWrapper();` Assign it values `wrap.panel = YOUR_PANEL;` `wrap.label = YOUR_LABEL;`. Add it to the map `map.put("YOU_STRING", wrap);`

Comment: Thanks nem. Thanks alot for your kind support

Answer (score 2):

No, not really.

The purpose of a map is to map from one thing to another: think of it as a source and a destination, or a label on a box and the contents of the box. There isn't room for a third "type of thing" in there.

It might be that what you really want is to map the `String` onto a *combination* of the other two; in other words, you want to look up both of the other values using the `String`; you want to store two things in the box. If so, you can certainly do that, but you need to create a new `Class panelAndLabel` that contains the other two items. You can then use that as the value type of your `HashMap`.

(Or, for a quick hack, the value could be of type `Object[]`, or `List<Object>`, and then you could put what you want into the value wrapper. But, as I say, that would be a bit of a hack.)

Answer (score 1):

[Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a nice data structure called a [Table](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html), for exactly this purpose.  Of course, another option is for you to roll your own, but I would use whats out there.

Comment: That wouldn't help him, he would like 1 key for a pair of values.